# JPA generating broken SQL when using native query and pageable

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring-Boot 2.7.7, when I attempt to create a native PostgreSQL query that receives a Pageable and outputs a Page, it seems to generate a broken SQL for one of the page attributes

This is the Query I used for the function:

```
    @Query(value ="SELECT * " +
            "FROM propriedade " +
            "INNER JOIN proprietario " +
            "  ON proprietario.id = propriedade.proprietario_id " +
            "WHERE proprietario.nome ILIKE %:proprietario% ",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    Page<Propriedade> findByProprietarioLikePage(Pageable pageable, @Param("proprietario") String proprietario);
```

When I try to call the function, it generates a few SQL commands, but breaks in this one:

```
Hibernate: select count(INNER) FROM propriedade INNER JOIN proprietario   ON proprietario.id = propriedade.proprietario_id WHERE proprietario.nome ILIKE ?   AND condominio_id = ? 
2023-08-07 10:34:57.361  WARN 319426 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2023-08-07 10:34:57.361 ERROR 319426 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
```

If I try to run this count on PSQL, I get the same error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: select count(INNER) FROM propriedade INNER JOIN proprietario...
                          ^
```

The problem seems to be with the generated query to count the entries in the table

Comment: How `Propriedade`looks like?

Comment: @Jens Propriedade shouldn't matter as the problem is the SQL generated by spring-boot, but it has a one-to-one relationship with another entity called Proprietario, in the database it has a column with the id. The native query works fine on psql, but spring is generating the count for the Page with a syntax error.

Comment: The sql will be generated from these objects. So it is very helpful to see them

Comment: BTW it looks like you have an attribute *inner* which is a keyword in sql.

Comment: It does not have an attribute "inner". The object has a few string attributes, and this many-to-one* relationship with Proprietario. None of the fields use sql keywords, as they are all in portuguese (I double-checked them just to be sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to add an alias, like "p", after "propriedade". It'll be like this:

```
@Query(value ="SELECT * " +
        "FROM propriedade p " +
        "INNER JOIN proprietario " +
        "  ON proprietario.id = p.proprietario_id " +
        "WHERE proprietario.nome ILIKE %:proprietario% ",
        nativeQuery = true
)
```

Comment: The SQL generator is indeed broken and it's using the first word after "propriedade", if I change from "INNER JOIN" to "LEFT JOIN" it would try to "count(LEFT)". Adding an alias to the table solved the issue because now it is doing a count(p) which despite generating an incorrect SQL statement, yields a correct result.